# django - saving list of base64 images

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

i have a django and django restframework project with postgres as database.
so i send a payload from frontend to this django project and this payload is json and have one field named images.
images is contain list of base64 images.
so i want to save them in database and i use code below for this field:

```
images = ArrayField(base_field=models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_images/'))
```

but when i want to save images i get this error:

```
images: ["The submitted data was not a file. Check the encoding type on the form."]
```

i understand that i have to decode base64 so that i can save them in imageField but how should i do that? how can i decode base64 this images in list one by one? or do you know a better way for this?

this are some of my codes:

serializer.py

```
class HotelsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    fields = ("id", "name", "stars", "address", "description", "number_of_floors",
              "number_of_rooms", "room_delivery_time", "room_empty_time",
               "images", "features")
    model = Hotel
```

models.py

```
class Hotel(models.Model):
"""
model for create a hotel
"""

name = models.CharField(max_length=60, unique=True)
stars = models.IntegerField()
address = models.CharField(max_length=150)
description = models.TextField(default="nitro hotel")
number_of_floors = models.IntegerField()
number_of_rooms = models.IntegerField()
room_delivery_time = models.TimeField()
room_empty_time = models.TimeField()
images = ArrayField(base_field=models.ImageField(upload_to='hotel_images/'))
features = models.JSONField()

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.name
```

views.py

```
class AddHotel(generics.CreateAPIView):
queryset = Hotel.objects.all()
serializer_class = HotelsSerializer
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that a b64 encoded image is not inherently a file, perhaps you can either change your model to hold a JSON or StringField.

Alternatively, you can convert your B64 to a file stream and upload it that way.

Utilizing Django's ContentFile class (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/files/file/#the-contentfile-class), you can initialize a file on the fly and try to save it.

```
image_file = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(data), name="smart_name.jpg")
```

This trick should work, you may need to pre-process the base-64 string depending on how you generate it.

Comment: i can't use string fields because i get error that the charachters is too long and how can i set data? i dont have any data in my models files

Comment: the data corresponds to b64 string, sorry I forgot to mention!

Comment: i tried that and the value i got after decoding is [<ContentFile: Raw content>]. and when i save that by serialize and get the values from database, i get a list of null, it's saving as null.

Comment: You may need to fix your base64 string prior to saving. Perhaps you could try to see if the image file is correctly created by .save() function.

Your base64 probably begins with a "data:image/png;base64," as the header for your data. You should strip the header part and get the data coming after the comma.